# py2exe/pyinstaller error for twilio api used for sending sms

Tags: py2exe, pyinstaller, twilio-api

I am making a simple application using twilio python 2.7 api.
My code is running standalone, but when I am converting my .py file to .exe file using py2exe or pyinstaller I am getting following error

[image]

setup.py (for py2exe) :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
    console=['test_sms.py'],
    options={
        'py2exe':{
            'packages':['twilio']
        }
    }
)
```